# Can't get pan gesture working

Tags: ios, swift, gestures

I'm trying to add a pan gesture using swift and I'm not able to get this working.  In trouble shooting this, I can only confirm that the handler is not getting called.  In have a subclass of UIViewController called RMConstructionViewController.  In this controller, I have a scrollView which contains a UIView which occupies the whole space as my contents.  Then, I am programmatically adding subviews to my contentView.  My complete view heirachy is as follows:

1. UIView -> RMConstructionViewController
2. UIScrollView -> scrollView
3. UIView -> My contentView
4. UIView -> programmatically added called upperView
5. UIView -> The view I want to pan called symbolView
6. UILabel -> I want symbolView to house a few items, but right now it only contains a single label and is sizedToFit the size of the label.

I guess I'm getting confused on what exactly is the target, etc.  Here is what I thought would work:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDatePan(_:)))
symbolView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

right after the above code, I immediate add my symbolView to the upperView:

```
upperView.addSubview(symbolView)
```

Then my handler is:

```
@IBAction func handleDatePan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(upperView)
        if gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x >= 0 && gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x <= currentRoadmap!.timeline!.width{
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPointMake(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            if gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x < 0 {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x = 0
            }
            if gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x > currentRoadmap!.timeline!.width {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x = currentRoadmap!.timeline!.width
            }
            gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0,0), inView: upperView)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code the "currentRoadmap!.timeline!.width equates to a CGFloat

Any ideas why I can't get the pan to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related due to `UIScrollView` has its own GestureRecognizer. The `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol has a method to allow multiple GestureRecognizers to handle the event simultaneously:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing (after a few hours of trying to get this to work) and added the code you mentioned above.  It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - finally.  When programmatically setting the gesture the target that worked is my class (self).  Then the only way to get this to work was to add my subview (symbolView) directly to scrollView.  So, there was something in the view hierarchy that I wanted to build that was prohibiting the pan gesture to work.  I don't actually know why the hierarchy is the problem, but I did get it to work.